# Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.3 desktop iso not booting from both DVD and USB

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, unetbootin

I tried booting Ubuntu desktop 14.04.3 from my DVD as well as USB stick by using all possible resources both in UEFI or legacy mode. In UEFI mode I changed the boot order and then when I boot it simply goes into my Windows 10 OS and in legacy mode it just goes to UNetbootin displaying default with 10 seconds countdown and again reboots to the same place.

Please help me I am using Dell Inspiron with insydeh20 boot menu with Windows 10 OS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot into the Windows system and disable hibernation. Open command prompt as administrator and execute:

   ```
   powercfg /h off
   ```

   Open Windows Control Panel - go to  Power Settings.
   Enable show hidden setting and uncheck fast startup.
   Shut down the computer completely - do NOT reboot.
2. Create a new proper installation media.
   UNetbootin is known to having issues.

   Use the diskpart tool from within the Windows system.
   Open command prompt as administrator and execute:

   ```
   diskpart
   list disk  
   select disk *  
   clean  
   create partition primary  
   active  
   format fs=fat32 quick  
   assign letter=**
   ```

   Note: * = number of USB drive | ** = select a free drive letter
   Mount the ISO file and copy the content to the USB drive.
3. Boot into BIOS and select the USB drive with the UEFI entry.

Comment: I can't understand assign letter step. Can u briefly explain it what does it do

Comment: @GauthamPughaz : You have to assign a letter to let Windows Explorer detect the drive, so that you can copy over something ... C: is the letter for the system for instance ... select letter X when it is not used ... :)